# Whats a good 17 inch work laptop with many cores and a large battery

Tags: laptop

Because of the nature of my work, I need a laptop with a big screen, 6-8 cores and a large battery. A network port would be good too, if possible. My budget is about 1200-2500$. But the problem is, I only either find gaming laptops with really expensive GPU's (and that run out of battery incredibly quick because of them, since they are always running) and lots of features I'll never even need  or incredibly expensive design Notebooks that are way above my budget (Like the XPS 17) that often don't even have any usb ports.

So whats a good laptop with some CPU horsepower, that can run for a long time without being plugged in and has a large screen?

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting requirements. Large screen, more physical cores will increase battery usage. Most higher core count CPUs in the 1K range are gaming laptops and all of them will have dedicated GPUs full-stop. Could you be a bit more specific on the nature of your work and applications? You may just be looking for a power saving core intel U/T/S/etc and a lower resolution screen (more bat life) paired with the max mAh battery possible.

Comment: Also in a pinch, [disabling the dedicated GPU will stop it from consuming power](https://superuser.com/questions/969107/fully-disabling-dedicated-graphic-card).

Comment: I do a lot of code compiling which would be sped up with a stronger cpu. Maybe your right and I'll get a low performance laptop anyway.

Comment: Do you know for sure it's your CPU that is increasing compile time? You could try and see if a development [RAMDISK](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-ram-disk-windows/) helps you. ImDisk is free. I think it would be best to stay away from a power saving series processor anyhow as they tend to be underclocked variants of the same CPU. If you're doing lots of simultaneous code compiling you will not want that. **Can you post your current specs for reference**, and we'll see what I can find for you as your budget is fairly generous. I'm assuming this is for USA.

Comment: CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U @ 8x 4GHz [49.0°C]
GPU: GeForce MX150
RAM: 4476MiB / 31876MiB
Battery has 48mah and holds a charge for about 2 hours

and it was a relatively cheaper laptop at 1000$ (although I did upgrade the ram). The main reason I want a powerful CPU ist that compilers can take advantage of multiple cores, which is why I would lean AMD. Also I'm not sure if a ramdisk helps with compiling, since its mostly happening in ram anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current laptop is actually quite decent, but as you are using a power savings CPU this is likely limiting your compile speed as mentioned.

The class of laptop you are looking for is a **workstation laptop**. These are typically sold for use in specialized business contexts. Because of your requirement of no GPU due to battery concerns, this means that we are forced to throw out a significant segment of the market as Gaming laptops are usually going to deliver best bang for the buck for the specs that you desire.

I decided to push your budget in favor of higher quality components.

### [DELL Precision 7750 Workstation $2,276.67](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/precision-7750-workstation/spd/precision-17-7750-laptop/xctop775017us_vivp?view=configurations&configurationid=f2a858fd-e92b-4b33-91c3-8f72419a8808)

- **Intel Xeon W-10885M (8 Core, 16MB Cache)**
- **Intel UHD Graphics (only, Integrated into CPU)**
- **95Whr 6 Cell Li-ion Battery**
- 32GB RAM (2x 16GB)
- Generic 256GB SSD (M.2 PCIe NVMe)

Because I am recommending a laptop you can buy from DELL directly, this configuration is customizable depending on what you want specifically. I've just pre-selected what I suspect you would desire (e.g. lowest resolution screen to reduce power consumption).

---

If you are seeking to lower the price I found a lower spec-ed configuration on [newegg for $1,174.99](https://www.newegg.com/gray-dell-precision-7750-mainstream/p/1TS-000A-0CK44?&quicklink=true), but I could only find refurbished laptops of the 17" size variant. At that price point I didn't think you would want to shoulder the risk of the battery already been somewhat worn and therefore sacrificing your battery life. You could also try looking on Amazon, but the spec filtering on there is rather lackluster.

---

A final note I would like to attach, is that if you find the performance to be sufficient, and want to extend battery life, you could try installing the [Intel XTU CPU utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29183/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-) and purposefully shortening the turbo boost time (recommended) or try undervolting (not recommended if you value system stability). Note that voltage has a squared relationship with power consumption, while frequency has a linear relationship.